# Is there anyway to list every files in my system

Tags: python-3.x

I want to list every file in my system eg: if drive d: exists it also should be listed or if drive g: exists it should also be listed like that every files should be listed is there anyway for that is CMD or Python or Powershell?

Thank you

Comment: Is ```os.listdir()``` what you want?

Comment: But every files should be listed for example if I am in d: drive the it should list all files in d: drive and c: and if e: drive exists then it should list including that also

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.